# Access mysql on netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I tried to do this tutorial

http://www.linglom.com/2007/12/05/accessing-mysql-on-netbeans-using-jdbc-part-i-create-a-connection/

but it gives me an error. I searched to understand what the error means, but i don't know.

the error said :

> Class Not Found Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I think the error : error when load mysql driver !!

I don't know how to correct the error !

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:
I add the jdbc driver (mysql-connector-java-5.0.7.zip) 
not the jdbc driver (mysql-connector-java-5.0.7.jar)